# Entity Framework with XML Files

Tags: c#, .net, xml, entity-framework

Is there a method to use an XML file instead of a database in the Entity Framework?

Comment: Do you mean manually editing EDMX instead of using the designer? Or XML as storage? Like bdukes says, the latter isn't supported (yet).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Entity Framework itself is provider-based, and is *designed* to operate over a relational database. If you really wanted to, you could write your own provider for EF that reads from/writes to an xml file, but it would be a *huge* amount of work.

I expect you should really be looking at one of:

- LINQ-to-XML
- XML (de)serialization
- XPath/XQuery
- XSLT

Entity Framework doesn't have a *natural* fit in this scenario.

Comment: If you really want to pursue a XML database, checkout this project: https://github.com/madskristensen/MiniBlog/blob/master/Website/app_code/code/Storage.cs

Answer (score 3):

Linq to XML isn't all that much actually. I'd go with a serializable solution instead.

Answer (score 2):

I like LINQ to XSD: http://linqtoxsd.codeplex.com/

It is basically LINQ to XML with some classes derived from the XSD to ensure it fits the schema...

Comment: i've found this tool very useful - however the context menu doesn't seem to show up in vs 2010..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's really possible.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> The ADO.NET Entity Framework is designed to enable developers to create data access applications by programming against a conceptual application model instead of programming directly against a *relational storage schema*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an oledb connection together with a FORXML command... but you will not have all functionality that is available with other providers...

Answer (score 0):

- Is the problem that you need a file-based data store? If so, you could use a SimpleDB data provider. SimpleDB is great if you need a relational database in a single file.  MS Access is great for this as well.
- XML is designed for communication. If used for storage, it is incredibly inefficient.  It might be best to break the two tasks apart and store your data in a relational database and then generate your XML from your data.

Comment: The question is about Entity Framework, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907 . Your answer seems to not take that into account.