# Entity Framework with File-Based Database

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, orm, sql-server-ce

I am in the process of developing a desktop application that needs a database.  The application is currently targeted to SQL Express 2005 and works wonderfully.  However, I'm not crazy about having this dependency on SQL Express and would prefer to use a small file-based database.

My problem is that I am using Entity Framework.  I have tried both SQL Compact and SQLite, and they both have bizarre problems with EF v1.  I get errors creating the Model, invalid models when it does get created... it's a nightmare.

I'm about ready to give up and write a data layer and repository in the good-old-school Connection/Command pattern.  Not my favorite plan...

**Is there a lightweight, file-based database out there that plays well with EF?**

OR

**Is there a better ORM tool that I should use instead of EF with my lightweight DB?**

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608477/entity-framework-with-xml-files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Mindscape LightSpeed](http://www.mindscape.co.nz/products/LightSpeed/default.aspx) has superb handling for file system databases (such as SQLite) and is free for small databases.

It's fairly straight forward to make the move as it has a LINQ provider, Visual Studio integrated designer (including supporting SQLite on the design surface) and there's significant help on getting up and running fast :-)

Comment: This looks interesting... I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to [Devart dotConnect for SQLite](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/)!

Answer (score 0):

I believe NHibernate supports both SQL Server Compact Edition and SQLite.  That is the route that I would recommend you take.

http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#configuration-optional-dialects

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2010 with Entity Framework 4.0 is now in Beta 2 and has a Go-Live license, so if you don't mind using beta software you can have all it's goodness now. I believe it has much better support for SQL Server Compact Edition.