# WPF application which creates XML instances

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Could you please suggest some solution for the following query?

I am writing a WPF application which can read from an XML schema, and show a designer UI to the user.The user can use the designer to add data and save it as an XML instance. He can reopen the the XML instance and view/edit the instance in the designer.

I am following the MVVM pattern to implement this. I will be writing model classes for the XML elements and bind it to the designer view. A data access layer will be populating the data in the model classes. I am very curious to know if there is any easy to use readymade "XML to Data Objects" which I will use as my data access layer. This data access layer needs to be efficient enough to hold just one XML instance in the memory and handle the read/save of XML instance.

Also, please feel free to comment on the overall approach I am taking in this design. I feel like this is a bit over complicated design, but can't help it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .NET Serializer will create the XML for you from you class. Here is a [MSDN example](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813) 
You just have to serialize it and it will act as a file db. You can also use entity framework to do so. [Here's a good StackOverflow question on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608477/entity-framework-with-xml-files)

Comment: Thanks Philippe, to clarify-do you prefer the serializer to linq-to-xml?

Comment: Actually, I prefer LINQ because it makes request like WHERE much more easy.

Comment: I also liked it, but I am not sure how easy to create the classes from the XML.

Comment: Take a look at http://blog.stevehorn.cc/2007/07/generate-code-from-xml-schema-xsdexe.html