# Can Entity framework creates tables in other databases?

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I am curious to know that if Entity framework can create tables in other databases besides MS-SQL ??
Moreover, is there any provision to create XML schema through EF ?

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood Entity Framework uses providers that are specific for different databases. So it depends on a provider whether EF can create tables or not. However, I haven't heard about providers that do not have this possibility. The easiest way to be sure is to write a simple program with a few lines of code.

As to XML schema. Are you asking about using XML files instead of database as the storage for your data? If so, again it depends on the provider. If you want you can theoretically create one that will use XML files. However, I haven't tried to do so and I don't think that it is a good idea. There are technologies that fit here better (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608477/entity-framework-with-xml-files)).